# How to check whether the OpenLDAP server is provider or consumer without doing a write on it?

Tags: openldap

1)Is there any monitoring or supervision attribute in the OpenLDAP server which can tell if the running OpenLDAP server is a provider or consumer without doing any operations on the Server like ldapmodify?
2) Is their any option to modify the syncrepl config online if yes then how to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both is to use the 'online configuration' mode whereby the configuration is held inside the directory. Then you can both look up for (1) and modify for (2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not able to do the online configuration.It always throws error when I do slapdtest -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d...52396722 ldif_write_entry: could not put entry file for "cn=config" in place: In
valid argument
52396722 config_build_entry: build "cn=config" failed: "(null)"
52396722 backend_startup_one (type=config, suffix="cn=config"): bi_db_open faile
d! (-1)
slap_startup failed (test would succeed using the -u switch)

Comment: Have you created the directory 'slapd.d'?

Comment: But I question why you want to know this. Normally you just do an update and get a referral error if the server is a slave. You can even configure OpenLDAP to do the referral itself so this isn't an application concern at all.

Comment: I created the slapd.d directory and tried but still the same error is appearing don't no why I am not able to convert slapd to online configuration mode,currently I am doing it using slapd.conf

Comment: I can now query using the monitor database whether the server is provider or consumer just by checking the MonitorIsShadow attribute if it is set to true then it is a slave if false then it is a writable/provider